# How can I add stock labels to option fields for configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I want to add stock labels to the options fields of my configurable products, but I don't understand how it works in Magento. I have read that I have to use the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable class. So I have created a little extension which uses this class, but there are some issues with my extension and I think this issuses exists because of a lack of knowledge.

**Details:**

My configurable products have configurable attributes like the following:
[image]

Furthermore if someone choose an option he will get something like this:
[image]

This looks great so far, but the values are sadly not correct.

Here is the core class of my extension:

```
<?php

class Fox_OutOfStockLabel_Block_Configurable extends
    Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
{
    public function getJsonConfig()
    {
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
        $attributes = array();
        $options = array();

        $allowedProducts = $this->getAllowProducts();
        $allowedAttributes = $this->getAllowAttributes();

        foreach ($allowedProducts as $product) {

            $productId = $product->getId();

            foreach ($allowedAttributes as $attribute) {

                $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                $attributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                $attributeCode = $productAttribute->getAttributeCode();
                $attributeValue = $product->getData($attributeCode);
                $attributeLabel = $product->getAttributeText($attributeCode);
                $qty = floor($product->getStockItem()->getQty());

                if (!isset($options[$attributeId])) {
                    $options[$attributeId] = array();
                }
                if (!isset($options[$attributeId][$attributeValue])) {
                    $options[$attributeId][$attributeValue] = array();
                }
                $options[$attributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
                $options['qty'][$attributeLabel] = $qty;
            }
        }

        $this->_resPrices = array(
            $this->_preparePrice($this->getProduct()->getFinalPrice())
        );

        foreach ($allowedAttributes as $attribute) {

            $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
            $attributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
            $attributeCode = $productAttribute->getAttributeCode();
            $attributeLabel = $attribute->getLabel();

            $info = array(
                'id' => $attributeId,
                'code' => $attributeCode,
                'label' => $attributeLabel,
                'options' => array()
            );

            $optionPrices = array();
            $prices = $attribute->getPrices();
            if (is_array($prices)) {
                foreach ($prices as $value) {
                    if (!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $label = $value['label'].$this->__(' (Out of stock)');
                    if ($options['qty'][$value['label']] > 0) {
                        $label = $value['label'].$this->__(' (%s in stock)', $options['qty'][$value['label']]);
                    }
                    $info['options'][] = array( 
                        'id' => $value['value_index'],
                        'label' => $label,
                        'price' => $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                        'qty' => isset($options[$attributeId][$value['label']]) ? $options[$attributeId][$value['label']] : array(),
                        'products' => isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']]) ? $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']] : array(),
                    );
                    $optionPrices[] = $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']);
                }
            }

            foreach ($optionPrices as $optionPrice) {
                foreach ($optionPrices as $additional) {
                    $this->_preparePrice(abs($additional - $optionPrice));
                }
            }
            if ($this->_validateAttributeInfo($info)) {
                $attributes[$attributeId] = $info;
            }
        }

        $_request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest(false, false, false);
        $_request->setProductClassId($this->getProduct()->getTaxClassId());
        $defaultTax = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($_request);

        $_request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest();
        $_request->setProductClassId($this->getProduct()->getTaxClassId());
        $currentTax = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($_request);

        $taxConfig = array(
            'includeTax' => Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax(),
            'showIncludeTax' => Mage::helper('tax')->displayPriceIncludingTax(),
            'showBothPrices' => Mage::helper('tax')->displayBothPrices(),
            'defaultTax' => $defaultTax,
            'currentTax' => $currentTax,
            'inclTaxTitle' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Incl. Tax'),
        );

        $config = array(
            'attributes' => $attributes,
            'template' => str_replace('%s', '#{price}', $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
//            'prices'          => $this->_prices,
            'basePrice' => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($this->getProduct()->getFinalPrice())),
            'oldPrice' => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($this->getProduct()->getPrice())),
            'productId' => $this->getProduct()->getId(),
            'chooseText' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Option wählen...'),
            'taxConfig' => $taxConfig,
        );

        return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($config);
    }
}
```

This will create the output from above. This output is not correct and it seems that the options will be overwritten at this position:

```
$options['qty'][$attributeLabel] = $qty;
```

because I have multiple products with the same attribute label. To avoid this behaviour I could change it to:

```
$options['qty'][$attributeLabel][$productId] = $qty;
```

But is this correct and the right way I have to go? I don't know, because I don't know when Magento will call the function **getJsonConfig**. Currently it seems that Magento is calling this function only if I visit the detail page of a configurable product, but Magento should calling this function after the selection of an option too, so that the options will be updated or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I could eliminate my lack of knowledge and found a solution which is working for me:

```
<?php

class Fox_StockLabel_Block_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
{
    public function getJsonConfig()
    {
        $attributes = array();
        $options = array();
        $optionsLabel = array();
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore();

        $allowedProducts = $this->getAllowProducts();
        $allowedAttributes = $this->getAllowAttributes();

        foreach ($allowedProducts as $product) {
            $productId = $product->getId();

            foreach ($allowedAttributes as $attribute) {
                $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                $attributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                $attributeCode = $productAttribute->getAttributeCode();
                $attributeValue = $product->getData($attributeCode);
                $attributeLabel = $product->getAttributeText($attributeCode);

                if (!isset($options[$attributeId])) {
                    $options[$attributeId] = array();
                }
                if (!isset($options[$attributeId][$attributeValue])) {
                    $options[$attributeId][$attributeValue] = array();
                }
                $options[$attributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;

                $qty = floor($product->getStockItem()->getQty());
                $options['qty'][$attributeLabel] += $qty;
            }
        }

        $this->_resPrices = array(
            $this->_preparePrice($this->getProduct()->getFinalPrice())
        );

        foreach ($allowedAttributes as $attribute) {
            array_push($optionsLabel, $attribute->getLabel()) ;
        }
        $numberOfOptions = count($optionsLabel);

        foreach ($allowedAttributes as $attribute) {
            $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
            $attributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
            $attributeCode = $productAttribute->getAttributeCode();
            $attributeLabel = $attribute->getLabel();

            $info = array(
                'id' => $attributeId,
                'code' => $attributeCode,
                'label' => $attributeLabel,
                'options' => array()
            );
            $optionPrices = array();
            $prices = $attribute->getPrices();
            if (is_array($prices)) {
                foreach ($prices as $value) {
                    if (!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ($attribute->getLabel() == $optionsLabel[$numberOfOptions - 1]) {
                        $products = $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']];
                        $numItems = count($products);
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $numItems; $i++) {
                            $a = array(0 => $products[$i]);
                            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products[$i]);
                            $currentItem = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products[$i]);

                            $qty = floor($stockItem->getQty());
                            $label = $value['label'] . $this->__(' (Out of stock)');
                            if ($qty > 0) {
                                $label = $value['label'] . $this->__(' (%s in stock)', $qty);
                            }
                            $info['options'][] = array(
                                'id' => $value['value_index'],
                                'label' => $label,
                                'price' => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($currentItem->getData('price'))) - $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($this->getProduct()->getPrice())),
                                'products' => isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']]) ? $a : array(),
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                        $label = $value['label'] . $this->__(' (Out of stock)');
                        if ($options['qty'][$value['label']] > 0) {
                            $label = $value['label'] . $this->__(' (%s in stock)', $options['qty'][$value['label']]);
                        }
                        $info['options'][] = array(
                            'id' => $value['value_index'],
                            'label' => $label,
                            'price' => $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                            'products' => isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']]) ? $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']] : array(),
                        );
                    }
                    $optionPrices[] = $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']);
                }
            }

            foreach ($optionPrices as $optionPrice) {
                foreach ($optionPrices as $additional) {
                    $this->_preparePrice(abs($additional - $optionPrice));
                }
            }
            if ($this->_validateAttributeInfo($info)) {
                $attributes[$attributeId] = $info;
            }
        }

        $_request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest(false, false, false);
        $_request->setProductClassId($this->getProduct()->getTaxClassId());
        $defaultTax = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($_request);

        $_request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest();
        $_request->setProductClassId($this->getProduct()->getTaxClassId());
        $currentTax = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($_request);

        $taxConfig = array(
            'includeTax'        => Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax(),
            'showIncludeTax'    => Mage::helper('tax')->displayPriceIncludingTax(),
            'showBothPrices'    => Mage::helper('tax')->displayBothPrices(),
            'defaultTax'        => $defaultTax,
            'currentTax'        => $currentTax,
            'inclTaxTitle'      => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Incl. Tax'),
        );

        $config = array(
            'attributes'        => $attributes,
            'template'          => str_replace('%s', '#{price}', $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
            'basePrice'         => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($this->getProduct()->getFinalPrice())),
            'oldPrice'          => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($this->getProduct()->getPrice())),
            'productId'         => $this->getProduct()->getId(),
            'chooseText'        => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Choose an Option...'),
            'taxConfig'         => $taxConfig,
        );

        return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($config);
    }
}
```